# Finding where function is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

\begin{align*}
f: z \mapsto f(z)&=\frac{az+b}{cz+d} \\
&\text{when $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$}
\end{align*}

- Where $f$ is analytic
- Where $f'(z)=0$
- Find inverse function for $f$ (if there is)

I tried to solve the first question with Cauchy-Riemann. Also $z=x+iy$ so:
$$\frac{a(x+iy)+b}{c(x+iy)+d}$$
Should I manipulate the function to $f=u(x,y)+i v(x,y)$ so I can find the first order partial derivates? And find points where $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ ?
Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find where $f$ is analytic, I recommend using the following facts:

- If two functions $g_1$ and $g_2$ are analytic, so is their composition $g_1\circ g_2$.
- If a function $g$ is analytic, so is the reciprocal function $1/g$ *wherever it is defined*.

You can do the other parts with a direct calculation.

Comment: Okey but what are $g_1$ and $g_2$ in this case? Isn't there a straight forward calculation with CR equations that I could do?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: You can do this problem with the Cauchy-Riemann equations. But for a problem like this it's easier to take functions that you know to be analytic, and then combine them in ways that you know preserve analyticity. It's like how you can take two continuous functions and when you add them the function you get is still continuous.

Comment: Can you help me do it with the cauchy-riemann equations